# Assign new value of Number in Number method

Tags: javascript

My goal is to add method to Number object which will change the value of number.
Like this

```
var a = 10;
a.add(5);
console.log(a); // Return 15
```

It is possible to do, or the only way is

```
Number.prototype.add = function(n) { return this.valueOf() + n; }
var a = 10;
a = a.add(5);
```

Thank you

Comment: Numbers in JavaScript are immutable, so you can't change them, only reassign them.  This is impossible to my knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that in JS, primitive values are immutable.

Theoretically, it would be possible to use a number object and alter its `[[NumberData]]` internal slot. However, ECMAScript provides no way to do that.

Instead, consider returning an object which, when coerced into a number with `valueOf`, returns the desired number, e.g.

```
function MyNumber(n) {
  this.number = n;
}
MyNumber.prototype.add = function(n) {
  this.number += n; return this;
};
MyNumber.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  return this.number;
};
var n = new MyNumber(10);
n.add(5);
n + 0; // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you or not. But javascript function currying can be useful . For example

```
function add(x){
  return function(o){
    return x+o;
   }
}
var a = add(4)(6);
document.getElementById('updateValue').textContent=a
```

[WORKING](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/6nsgghLa/)